# mPDF background image speed problems

Tags: php, mpdf

I have a problem with css background image on live server.

On local server (windows7 + xampp) any pdf with background image for each page is generating very fast (1-2 seconds).

On live server (linux) same pdf is generating in about 10-15 seconds...

And it's not a matter of image size - it can be small pixel image, and it takes very long time as well.

After commenting background url in css, it works OK. Any ideas?

I am using **mpdf 6.1, php 5.6**

My CSS code for image background for each page:

```
@page{ 
size: 21cm 29.7cm; margin: 40mm 10mm 20mm 10mm; 
background: #ffffff url(/background.jpg) no-repeat; 
background-size: cover; 
}
```

Comment: My css code for image background for each page:

@page{
    size: 21cm 29.7cm;
    margin: 40mm 10mm 20mm 10mm;
    background: #ffffff url(/background.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

Comment: You can always edit your question to add some info (like the CSS code for example)